# What does I1001 mean in a METAR remarks?

Tags: metar

Here is an actual METAR example:

```
KOMA 190352Z 36017G26KT 3SM -SN OVC012 M08/M11 A3014
RMK AO2 PK WND 36027/0302 FZDZE37SNB27 SLP220 P0000 I1001 T10831111 $
```

What does the `I1001` mean? I have also seen `I1000`, `I1002`, `I1003`, and `I1004`.

Comment: Are you sure it's a capital i and not the digit 1?

Comment: Yes, it is capital "i". I copy and pasted the METAR. If you goggle I1001 you might get some METARs with it. https://www.google.com/search?q=metar+i1001

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It indicates ice accretion (buildup). This seems to be very obscure, I finally found it in [some NOAA release notes](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:N5haqnh0oaQJ:www.nws.noaa.gov/ops2/Surface/documents/release_notes_307_draft.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&lr=lang_en%7Clang_es) for ASOS software v3.07:

> 36. (S01126) ADD ICE ACCRETION REMARK TO METAR/SPECI REPORTS
>
> Discussion: The amount of ice accreting on a flat surface (planar
>   icing) as estimated by the data from the freezing rain sensor, will be
>   included in the remarks section of the METAR / SPECI reports. The
>   remark will have the format of “Ihnnn,” where “h” is the hourly time
>   period, i.e., 1, 3 or 6 hours. The value “nnn” is the ice thickness
>   accumulated to the nearest 0.01 inch.
>
> Please Note: In situations when FZRASN is manually entered in the
>   Present Weather field, an inappropriate trace accretion amount (I1000,
>   I3000, I6000) might be entered in the remarks section of the METAR /
>   SPECI reports. This is a known issue and will be addressed at a later
>   time.

Based on that, "I1001" means ice buildup of 0.01 inches in the last 1 hour.

And thanks to Jimmy for finding a more official source: [*FCM-H1-2017, Federal Meteorological Handbook No. 1 - Surface Weather Observations and Reports*](https://www.ofcm.gov/publications/fmh/FMH1/FMH1_2017.pdf) (p. 12-18) from OFCM, the Office of the Federal Coordinator for Meteorology.

Comment: That is correct, but a better source would be the NOAA instruction manual for putting together METARs and other observations.  FCM-H1-2017, Para 12.7.2.i.  https://www.ofcm.gov/publications/fmh/FMH1/FMH1_2017.pdf
Ice Accretion was added to the handbook about a year ago.

Comment: @Jimmy Great find! I've added that to my answer